# Como ordenar o resultado de uma query por uma coluna onde haja um valor noutra coluna na mesma tabela?

Tags: sql, select, value

Tenho uma tabela com várias coluna, e quero ordenar os resultados pelos valores de uma das coluna onde outra coluna na mesma tabela seja igual a um valor.

Já experimentei implementar a query com `CASE`, `IF's` e `FIELD()`.

Quero que seja apresentado os resultados ordenados por tech.value quando tech.id_color = 5

Aqui está a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM products, tech_products 
WHERE products.idsub = 1 AND 
    tech_products.id = products.id 
ORDER by tech.id_cor = 5 AND tech.value ASC
```

Comment: Só quer ordenar quando for tech.id_cor = 5?
Ou só quer resultados onde tech.id_cor = 5?

Comment: @MarceloVieira quero ordenar pelo tech.id_cor = 5. Mas já agora como é que se faz para a maneira de aparecer os resultados onde tech.id_cor = 5?

Comment: Não conheço a estrutura do seu banco, mas acredito que queira algo assim: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products, tech_products, tech
WHERE 
products.idsub = 1 AND 
tech_products.idProduto = products.id AND
tech.idProduto = products.id AND
tech.id_cor = 5
ORDER by tech.value ASC

Comment: Não resultou, o pretendido é ter um ORDER BY tech.value quando tech.id_cor = 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM products, tech_products 
WHERE products.idsub = 1 AND 
    tech_products.id = products.id 
ORDER by (case when (tech.id_cor = 5) then 0 else 1 end) ASC,
         tech.id_cor
```

A síntaxe do CASE poe variar conforme o BD , mas creio que resolva.

Comment: Não, tech,value não é boolean. É um valor especifíco/número.

Comment: Editei a resposta